# How to run migration code in DBeaver or UI tool

Tags: database, dbeaver

I have a question that I do not know the answer.
I have this code

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('AAAA', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('WWW');
        });

        Schema::table('BBBBB', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('CCCCC');
        });
    }
```

My question is if it is possible to run this commands / script in DBeaver?
to do this operation via UI tool?

Comment: It's a bit strange question. No, it is not possible to run PHP script in DBeaver or any other UI tool. There is SQL for that, like: `ALTER TABLE AAAA DROP COLUMN WWW;ALTER TABLE BBB DROP COLUMN CCCC;`

Comment: TNX just wants to make sure, if exists such option it would be great